# What is it that controls the dlls that SearchUI.exe (Cortana) loads when running?

Tags: dll, cortana

I am troubleshooting an issue I'm having with SearchUI (Cortana).

(see [Cortana starts being slow and laggy after launch of the UFT (Unified Functional Testing) application](https://superuser.com/questions/1509589/cortana-starts-being-slow-and-laggy-after-launch-of-the-uft-unified-functional))

I have narrowed it down to this dll, EventHooks.dll that SearchUI tries and fails to load when it starts running.  If I rename the dll, SearchUI starts working properly again.

However, I'm thinking that there is some way to tell SearchUI to just not try to load this dll at all,  Where can we control this setting?

Here's an extract from the debugger output

```
'SearchUI.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\HPE\Unified Functional Testing\bin64\EventsHook.dll'
'SearchUI.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\HPE\Unified Functional Testing\bin64\EventsHook.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SearchUI.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\HPE\Unified Functional Testing\bin64\EventsHook.dll'
'SearchUI.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\HPE\Unified Functional Testing\bin64\EventsHook.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SearchUI.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SearchUI.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleacc.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SearchUI.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp140.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SearchUI.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleacc.dll'
'SearchUI.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp140.dll'
'SearchUI.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140.dll'
'SearchUI.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\HPE\Unified Functional Testing\bin64\EventsHook.dll'
'SearchUI.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\HPE\Unified Functional Testing\bin64\EventsHook.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SearchUI.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\HPE\Unified Functional Testing\bin64\EventsHook.dll'
'SearchUI.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\HPE\Unified Functional Testing\bin64\EventsHook.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SearchUI.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SearchUI.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp140.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SearchUI.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleacc.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SearchUI.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleacc.dll'
'SearchUI.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp140.dll'
'SearchUI.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140.dll'
'SearchUI.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\HPE\Unified Functional Testing\bin64\EventsHook.dll'
d:\os\src\shellcommon\shell\cortana\core\src\userauthenticationmanager.cpp(861)\Cortana.Core.dll!00007FFD8B00C6E1: (caller: 00007FFD8B295FF6) ReturnHr(118) tid(41c4) 80070490 Élément introuvable.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFDBA1DA388 (KernelBase.dll) in SearchUI.exe: 0x40080201: WinRT originate error (parameters: 0x0000000080070490, 0x0000000000000016, 0x000000554DBFEC10).
d:\os\src\shellcommon\shell\cortana\common\utilities\inc\cortanaregistryhelpers.h(44)\SearchUI.exe!00007FF6CAB76C67: (caller: 00007FF6CAA5FB0F) ReturnHr(28) tid(1f84) 80070002 Le fichier spécifié est introuvable.
    CallContext:[\CortanaApp_HandleActivationFromLaunch\CortanaApp_Initialize\AppStateManager_PerformFinalActivationActivities] 
d:\os\src\shellcommon\shell\cortana\common\utilities\inc\cortanaregistryhelpers.h(44)\Cortana.Core.dll!00007FFD8AFBBFD2: (caller: 00007FFD8AFD648E) ReturnHr(119) tid(1f84) 80070002 Le fichier spécifié est introuvable.
d:\os\src\shellcommon\shell\cortana\core\src\settings\configurationmanager.cpp(2711)\Cortana.Core.dll!00007FFD8AFD64AE: (caller: 00007FF6CAA5FBE6) LogHr(28) tid(1f84) 80070002 Le fichier spécifié est introuvable.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFDBA1DA388 in SearchUI.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Platform::COMException ^ at memory location 0x000000554DBFF128. HRESULT:0x80070490 Élément introuvable.
WinRT information: Élément introuvable.
Stack trace:
 >[External Code]
 >CortanaApi.dll!00007ffd8b2bff7f()
 >CortanaApi.dll!00007ffd8b29603a()
 >CortanaApi.dll!00007ffd8b200891()
 >CortanaApi.dll!00007ffd8b1ff999()
 >SearchUI.exe!00007ff6ca9c84ae()
 >SearchUI.exe!00007ff6caa5f287()
 >SearchUI.exe!00007ff6caa1ed88()
 >[External Code]
```

Comment: "fails to load" - what if any is the error message?

Comment: see edit in question

Comment: So there is a bug in UFT. Report it to them.

Comment: that sounds like that would solve my issue ... maybe in a year or so, I'd rather find a way to fix it myself

Comment: {shrug} Well we can't fix it. And if you don't report it it will never get fixed.

Comment: I'm no expert, but it looks like UFT is injecting something into this process.  Wouldn't there be a way to remove it?  I already have a fix for it, which is to rename the dll.  But I'd rather fix whatever is trying to call the dll

Comment: UFT is trying to load **it's own DLL** and failing because there is a missing file. `C:\Program Files (x86)\HPE\Unified Functional Testing\bin64\EventsHook.dll` - **Cannot find or open the PDB file.**

Comment: I think you got it wrong, the 'Cannot open the PDB file' also happen on a bunch of other DLLs from my extract, yet they aren't part of the problem

Comment: That's because the request gets passed on up the chain of DLLs ...

Comment: While agree with conclusion this is caused by a third-party application (HPE).  It is not clear what version of Windows 10 you are using.

Comment: WIn 10 1803.  Of course HPE UFT is the culprit, doesn't change the fact that there could be something that I could do about it ... my question isn't even directly on the error itself, I'm asking about SearchUI behaviour.  I don't understand the arguing